# Placing node relative to legend

Tags: pgfplots

> Sorry for the lengthy example but when I tried shorting it I just messed things up. Don't mind the overlapping bars. If used in the main document the lines are properly sized.

I have been trying to place some text above my legend which kind of works (line 77 and 90). However I would like to have the node located centred and above the legend automatically. I have found [this](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/sub-series/) but have not had any luck transferring it to my problem. The name "legend" (set in line 66) is supposedly unknown.

The desired result:
[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomA   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.000   0.001   0.017   0.907   0.061   0.015   0.000
Madrid  0.000   0.008   0.010   0.857   0.125   0.000   0.000
Larnaca 0.000   0.005   0.013   0.749   0.233   0.000   0.000
Copenhagen  0.000   0.000   0.004   0.966   0.030   0.000   0.000
Belgrade    0.000   0.002   0.018   0.886   0.094   0.000   0.000
Banja~Luka  0.000   0.000   0.004   0.953   0.043   0.000   0.000
}\roomA

\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomB   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.01    0.07    0.01    0.90    0.02    0.00    0.00
Madrid  0.00    0.00    0.01    0.97    0.02    0.00    0.00
Larnaca 0.00    0.01    0.02    0.98    0.00    0.00    0.00
Copenhagen  0.00    0.02    0.03    0.95    0.00    0.00    0.00
Belgrade    0.00    0.01    0.03    0.96    0.00    0.00    0.00
Banja~Luka  0.00    0.00    0.01    0.78    0.21    0.00    0.00
}\roomB

\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomC   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.00    0.00    0.01    0.86    0.11    0.03    0.00
Madrid  0.00    0.00    0.04    0.87    0.08    0.01    0.00
Larnaca 0.00    0.00    0.01    0.76    0.20    0.04    0.00
Copenhagen  0.00    0.00    0.02    0.94    0.04    0.00    0.00
Belgrade    0.00    0.00    0.04    0.90    0.06    0.00    0.00
Banja~Luka  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.83    0.17    0.00    0.00
}\roomC


\pgfplotsset{xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    xmax=100,
    ymin=-0.75,         % Start x axis at 0
    ymax=5.75,
    %xtick=\empty, 
    %ytick=\empty,
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    %yticklabels from table={\roomA}{RoomA},  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    unit vector ratio=1 11, % changing the aspect ratio of the immage
    }   


\begin{axis}[bar shift=11, bar width=8, axis x line = none, axis y line = none]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};    
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[bar shift=-11, bar width=8, axis x line = none, axis y line = none, legend style={draw=none, 
                        fill=none, 
                        at={(0.5,1.02)},
                        anchor= south,
                        name=legend,
                        },
                        legend columns={7}, area legend]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};    
\legend{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} %Bh, Ch,Oh
\coordinate(aboveLegend) at (axis cs:50,6.6);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=0, bar width=8, ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\roomA}{RoomA}, xtick={0,20,...,100}, xlabel={time [\%]}]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};    
\end{axis}

\node at (aboveLegend){Climate categories };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noting that  `legend` is just a `tikz` `node`, you can put a label to it:

```
legend style={draw=none,
              fill=none,
              at={(0.5,1.02)},
              anchor= south,
              name=legend,
              label=above : Climate categories     %%% <----- here
            },
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomA   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.000   0.001   0.017   0.907   0.061   0.015   0.000
Madrid  0.000   0.008   0.010   0.857   0.125   0.000   0.000
Larnaca 0.000   0.005   0.013   0.749   0.233   0.000   0.000
Copenhagen  0.000   0.000   0.004   0.966   0.030   0.000   0.000
Belgrade    0.000   0.002   0.018   0.886   0.094   0.000   0.000
Banja~Luka  0.000   0.000   0.004   0.953   0.043   0.000   0.000
}\roomA

\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomB   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.01    0.07    0.01    0.90    0.02    0.00    0.00
Madrid  0.00    0.00    0.01    0.97    0.02    0.00    0.00
Larnaca 0.00    0.01    0.02    0.98    0.00    0.00    0.00
Copenhagen  0.00    0.02    0.03    0.95    0.00    0.00    0.00
Belgrade    0.00    0.01    0.03    0.96    0.00    0.00    0.00
Banja~Luka  0.00    0.00    0.01    0.78    0.21    0.00    0.00
}\roomB

\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
RoomC   Oc  Cc  Bc  A   Bh  Ch  Oh
Porto   0.00    0.00    0.01    0.86    0.11    0.03    0.00
Madrid  0.00    0.00    0.04    0.87    0.08    0.01    0.00
Larnaca 0.00    0.00    0.01    0.76    0.20    0.04    0.00
Copenhagen  0.00    0.00    0.02    0.94    0.04    0.00    0.00
Belgrade    0.00    0.00    0.04    0.90    0.06    0.00    0.00
Banja~Luka  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.83    0.17    0.00    0.00
}\roomC


\pgfplotsset{xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    xmax=100,
    ymin=-0.75,         % Start x axis at 0
    ymax=5.75,
    %xtick=\empty,
    %ytick=\empty,
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    %yticklabels from table={\roomA}{RoomA},  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    unit vector ratio=1 11, % changing the aspect ratio of the immage
    }


\begin{axis}[bar shift=11, bar width=8, axis x line = none, axis y line = none]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomA};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[bar shift=-11, bar width=8, axis x line = none, axis y line = none, legend style={draw=none,
                        fill=none,
                        at={(0.5,1.02)},
                        anchor= south,
                        name=legend,
                        label=above : Climate categories     %%% <----- here
                        },
                        legend columns={7}, area legend]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomC};
\legend{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} %Bh, Ch,Oh
%\coordinate(aboveLegend) at (axis cs:50,6.6);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=0, bar width=8, ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\roomA}{RoomA}, xtick={0,20,...,100}, xlabel={time [\%]}]
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Cc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bc}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=SeaGreen] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{A}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Bh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=purple] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Ch}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=100*\thisrow{Oh}, y expr=\coordindex] {\roomB};
\end{axis}

%\node at (aboveLegend){Climate categories};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]