# pgfplots named legend incompatibility with beamer handout?

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

Please consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t, fleqn, 
    %,handout %% "handout" for one page per slide 
]{beamer} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
                xmin=0, xmax=11, 
                ymin=-10, ymax=10, domain=0:10,
                axis x line = center, 
                axis y line = center,
                axis line style = {thick, gray},
                xlabel = {$t$},
                every axis x label/.append style = {below, gray},
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},
                legend style={at={(1.1,1)}, anchor=north west, nodes=right, name=leg},
                clip mode = individual,
            ]
            \only<+->{
                \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {2*x-10};
                \addlegendentry{one};
            }
            \only<+->{
                \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {5*sin(deg(x))};
                \addlegendentry{two};
            }
            \only<+->{
                \node at (leg.south) [below=10pt, align=center,draw]
                    {$\Uparrow$ \\ \textbf{THIS}};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives the expected sequence of three slides:

[image: correct sequence of slides]

where the last nodes appear below the legend. If I uncomment the `%, handout` line in the header, I have this error:

```
/home/romano/tmp/testleg.tex|44 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named leg is known.
```

with the corresponding label misplaced:

[image: wrong node in the handout output]

How can I avoid this problem? I tried various combination of `fragile`, and specification with `<+|handout=1>` around, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/how-can-i-place-a-node-relative-to-a-legend), you can add nodes relative to the legend `leg` only outside of the axis environment. This is the copy of your example with that small change:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t, fleqn, 
%handout %% "handout" for one page per slide 
]{beamer} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{title}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=11, 
        ymin=-10, ymax=10, domain=0:10,
        axis x line = center, 
        axis y line = center,
        axis line style = {thick, gray},
        xlabel = {$t$},
        every axis x label/.append style = {below, gray},
        ylabel = {$y(t)$},
        legend style={at={(1.1,1)}, anchor=north west, nodes=right, name=leg},
        clip mode = individual,
        ]
        \only<+->{
            \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {2*x-10};
            \addlegendentry{one};
        }
        \only<+->{
            \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {5*sin(deg(x))};
            \addlegendentry{two};
        }
        \end{axis}
        \only<+->{
            \node at (leg.south) [below=10pt, align=center,draw]
            {$\Uparrow$ \\ \textbf{THIS}};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug.  This hack solves it. As an aside, frametitle takes two arguments, not one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t, fleqn, 
    handout %% "handout" for one page per slide 
]{beamer} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgfplots}%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}{}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
                xmin=0, xmax=11, 
                ymin=-10, ymax=10, domain=0:10,
                axis x line = center, 
                axis y line = center,
                axis line style = {thick, gray},
                xlabel = {$t$},
                every axis x label/.append style = {below, gray},
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},
                legend style={at={(1.1,1)}, anchor=north west, nodes=right, name=leg},
                clip mode = individual,
            ]
              \node (leg){};
               \only<+->{
                \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {2*x-10};
                \addlegendentry{one};
            }
            \only<+->{
                \addplot+ [smooth, mark=none] {5*sin(deg(x))};
                \addlegendentry{two};
            }
            \only<+->{
                \node at (leg.south) [below=10pt, align=center,draw]
                    {$\Uparrow$ \\ \textbf{THIS}};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The subtitle is no mandatory argument for `\frametitle`. Including an empty `{}` may even cause problems, e.g. we had a question about `beamerarticle` where this introduced additional vertical spacing as it was not recognised as empty.

Comment: But if you give one inadvertently, you can mess things up quite a bit, as I once found out the hard way.....

Comment: Sounds interesting -- do you happen to remember what was messed up without the second argument?

Comment: The workaround avoid the error, but unfortunately not the problem: the "This" node is still at wrong place, and not under the legend box, as in the correct (no `handout` case).

Comment: Hmmm... `beamuserguide.pdf` say that `frametitle` is: `\frametitle<⟨overlay specification⟩>[⟨short frame title⟩]{⟨frame title text⟩}` --- (v3.36, section 8.2.6, page 71). From where is that two-argument thing? I never used them... just curious.